# sending file attachment via html form sends big junk of text to the email body

Tags: php, email, attachment

I am trying to make a html file upload to send via email with php. Here is the code snippet:

```
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 
        $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
        $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

        $body="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

        --_1_$boundary
        Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

        --_2_$boundary
        Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

        test

        --_2_$boundary--
        --_1_$boundary
        Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
        Content-Disposition: attachment 

        $attachment
        --_1_$boundary--";

        mail('email@example.com', 'Leidige stillinger', $body, $headers) or die("NO");
```

I get the email but with a junk of text, looks like the $boundary generates that big junk of text. Or I am doing this all wrong, first I have to upload the file somewhere in the server then send it via email

Answer (score 0):

I've always preferred hand-rolling the MIME encoding as well, like you're doing, instead of using a library.  You're close.  Try this:

```
    // to, from, subject, message body, attachment filename, etc.
    $to = "to@to.com";
    $from = "from@from.com";
    $subject = "subject";
    $message = "this is the message body";
    $filename="/home/user/file.pdf";  //location of file - path and filename
    $fname="file.jpeg";               //name of file for display purposes 

    $headers = "From: $from"; 
    // boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    // multipart boundary 
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // preparing attachments            
        $file = fopen($filename,"rb");
        $data = fread($file,filesize($fname));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$fname\"\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$fname\"\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";


    $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f " . $from);
```